# mysql regular expression for exact one or two word match

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I was going to use the following code to display some sales numbers for 100 car brands:

```
$brand = str_replace ('-', '[- ]', $_GET['brand']);

$sql = "SELECT year, brand, number FROM `exampletable` WHERE brand REGEXP :brand ORDER BY `year` DESC";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":brand", $brand);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->rowCount())
{ while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
<?php echo $result['year'];?>
<?php echo $result['number'];?>

<?php }} else { echo '0'; } ?>
```

Now this code works fine for 98 brands in my table, but there's a problem with the following brands because they contain the same word:

- "Renault" and "Matra Renault"
- "Volkswagen" and "Volkswagen Porsche"

As a result the numbers for "Matra Renault" not only appear on the specific webpage for that brand, but also on the webpage for "Renault". The same thing happens for "Volkswagen" where I see the numbers for "Volkswagen Porsche" as well.

So, I completely understand why my code doesn't work, but I don't have enough knowledge about this topic to find a quick solution. I've already read older questions here but none of them seemed to discuss the same problem.

Note: As no other data will be added to my table in the future, a solution specifically for the above mentioned brands would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're selecting with `REGEXP`, while you apparently don't need it. The regular expression means `Volkswagen` will match anything with `Volkswagen` in the brand's name, so you get those other unwanted results, specifically because your regular expression is just the whole brand name.

Note, incidentally, that  searching for `Volkswagen Porsche` won't return `Volkswagen`, because `Porsche` is not in it. See [this simplified example](https://regex101.com/r/LRhErw/1/) vs [this](https://regex101.com/r/7cxsTG/1).

The solution to your problem would be to simply select the exact name of the brand you're looking for with `=`:

```
$sql = "SELECT year, brand, number FROM `exampletable` WHERE brand = :brand ORDER BY `year` DESC";
```

And another solution, though total overkill, would be to fix your regular expression to match the words exactly:

```
$brand = "^".$brand."\$";
```

Then, it'll only look for exact matches. [See example](https://regex101.com/r/ilsKKY/1)

Comment: When I would use `=` , I would have no numbers for a brand with two words like "Land Rover" for example.

Comment: Why wouldn't you? Does the `brand` field have any modifications? Did you try it? How about the second solution?

Comment: First line of code: the brand name in the url that I get is land-rover.
The brand name stored in the table is Land Rover.
As a result, I don't get any results when I use `=`.

Comment: Oh! I see, so your problem is not spacing, but casing. Try it like this: `$sql = "SELECT year, brand, number FROM exampletable WHERE LOWERCASE(brand) = :brand ORDER BY year DESC";`

Comment: Unfortunatley that doesn't work. The first line of code `$brand = str_replace ('-', '[- ]', $_GET['brand']);` changes "land-rover" to "land[- ]rover". Then by using REGEXP it matches with the brand name "Land Rover" stored in my table. That first line of code is necessary because of brand names like "Land Rover" and "Rolls-Royce", unless there's another solution for that...

Comment: I just got what that meant, it's an OR group in the regex :). There *are* other solutions but they would require to change some more stuff. To keep it simple, please try the second solution I posted (adding ^ and $ at the beginning and end)

Comment: Great! I'll edit the answer in a bit to reflect the comments. Now that you got it working: what I would do is store the slug in the database upon saving along the complete name. Then, you only do the slugging once, and you can avoid the `REGEXP` call which is *really* slow (you can't even use indexes) and will bring you problems further down the road. Then, simply compare `$brand` with `slug` instead of `brand`.

Comment: @ishegg - If you have the default collation, `LOWERCASE()` is a waste.

Comment: @Stan - Adding `INDEX(brand)` will speed up the query (once you switch from `REGEXP` to `=`.

Comment: @RickJames Yeah, I figured that he didn't have a case insensitive collation because it wasn't working, but the problem was elsewhere. Thanks!